# Load entity without associations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Let's say I have the following entities and associations:

Entity A:

```
@Entity
public class A {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "a", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<B> b;

}
```

Entity B:

```
@Entity
public class B {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
private A a;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<C> c;

}
```

Entity C:

```
@Entity
public class C {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
private B b;

}
```

Using the `.findAll()` method of the `CrudRepository` for entity `A`, it will return each `A` with its associated `B`'s in a list. Also, each `B` will have each of its associated `C`'s in a list.

My question is: If I in some cases only want to load all `A`'s with their `B`'s, but I don't want the `C`'s in the `B`'s, would that be possible? Could I create a custom query to do that, or is there another way? I hope it is clear what I want to achieve.

Comment: Consider having a look at entity graphs.

Comment: I will try to see if I can get it working with Entity Graphs. However, since `@OneToMany` by default is `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, shouldn't that prevent `List<C> c;` in entity `B` from being loaded when entity `A` is loaded?

Comment: I've been searching for an answer to this for at least 2 days now. I have also tried using `EntityGraphs`. It seems like what I want to achieve here is simply impossible. Guess I will just have to accept that every association will be loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is `mappedBy` values in `one` side of `OneToMany` relationships. 
`mappedBy` value must be the **the name of variable in the other side**. So in your cases, you can do this:

1. In Entity A: change `mappedBy = "citizen"` to `mappedBy = "a"`
2. In Entity B: change `mappedBy = "citizen"` to `mappedBy = "b"`

I know Entity a,b,c is just an example, but you should follow above pattern when designing your models relationships.

Comment: Sorry, as you said, A, B and C are just examples. I copied the code from a project of mine and forgot to change the names in `mappedBy`. I have configured this the right way in my project, so this is not the cause of the problem.